# EventEmitter not catching event

Tags: angular, typescript, dat.gui

I've been trying to get my toolbar component to emit data to another component (dat.gui -> three.js). What I assumed would be needed is creating an output emitter and that is working, but it is not working somehow. There is no actual html code inside these components.

All I need to do is emit the event with the interface holding data (currently just a `boolean`, but will be expanded later). My project is also on github, if that would be clearer. I ve been reading up on a variety of ways to work with Angular, but am still pretty new. In that regard, if I made a dumb mistake please tell me because I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

https://github.com/GrimZero/ConfiguratorAngular

settngs.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SettingsService {

  $dataChange: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
}
```

toolbar.component.ts

```
import { GUI } from './../../../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module';
import { Settings } from '../settings';
import { SettingsService } from '../settings.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']

})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  settingsData: Settings;

  constructor(private service: SettingsService) {
    this.settingsData = this.defineSettings({ TimeNight: false });
  }

  defineSettings(config: Settings) {
    const settings = { TimeNight: true };

    if (config.TimeNight) {
      settings.TimeNight = config.TimeNight;
    }

    return settings;
  }

  onChange() {
    this.service.$dataChange.next(this.settingsData);
    console.log('emitted');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const gui = new GUI();
    gui.add(this.settingsData, 'TimeNight').onChange(() => {
      this.onChange();
    });
  }
}
```

threejs.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Material } from '../material.js';
import { TimeOfDay } from '../time-of-day.js';
import { Threejscontroller } from '../threejscontroller.js';
import { SettingsService } from '../settings.service.js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-threejs',
  templateUrl: './threejs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']
})
export class ThreejsComponent implements OnInit {
  threejs: Threejscontroller;

  constructor(private service: SettingsService) { }

  updateWebGL = (settingsData: any) => {
    console.log('recieved message');

    if (!settingsData.TimeNight) {
      new TimeOfDay().SetTimeDay(this.threejs.scene);
    } else {
      new TimeOfDay().SetTimeDusk(this.threejs.scene);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.$dataChange.subscribe((value: any) => {
      console.log(value);
      // this.updateWebGL(value);
    });

    this.threejs = new Threejscontroller();
    this.threejs.update();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could only use `@Output` to pass data from child component to parent component. I think here your approach is wrong

So you have to achieve it by using a service:

Defined a Service like bellow

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    $dataChange: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
}
```

Make sure to add it to your `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({    
    providers: [
        MyService
    ]
})
```

And inject it to `ThreejsComponent` and use it like bellow

```
export class ThreejsComponent implements OnInit {
  threejs: Threejscontroller;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  UpdateWebGL = (settingsData: Settings) => {
    console.log('recieved message');

    if (!settingsData.TimeNight) {
      new TimeOfDay().SetTimeDay(this.threejs.scene);
    } else {
      new TimeOfDay().SetTimeDusk(this.threejs.scene);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.threejs = new Threejscontroller();
    this.threejs.update();

    this.myService.$dataChange.subscribe((value: any) => {
            this.UpdateWebGL(value);
        });
  }
}
```

In `ToolbarComponent` use like bellow:

```
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  settingsData: Settings;

  @Output() event: EventEmitter<Settings> = new EventEmitter<Settings>();

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.settingsData = this.defineSettings({ TimeNight: false });
  }

  defineSettings(config: Settings) {
    const settings = { TimeNight: true };

    if (config.TimeNight) {
      settings.TimeNight = config.TimeNight;
    }

    return settings;
  }

  onChange() {
    this.myService.$dataChange.next(this.settingsData);
    console.log("emitted");

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const gui = new GUI();
    gui.add(this.settingsData, 'TimeNight').onChange(() => {
      this.onChange();
    });
  }
}
```

I checked your git code, the issue with your imports please change the import of `ThreejsComponent`

```
import { SettingsService } from '../settings.service.js';
```

to

```
import { SettingsService } from '../settings.service';
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hmm that didn't quite work. That is giving me a pretty significant error saying that my UpdateWebGL is not a function. Naturally, because my toolbar does not have that function. This will update my scene and thus needs to be called in the threejs.component to correctly reference the data. These components are not linked to each other though, and I am also not dead set on this approach. All I need is an interface passing between components, and calling a function when that happens.

Comment: yeah, that is correct since it is not in your tool bar component. you have to define it there. or you have define your event in wrong component

Comment: But if I define it there I need to reference the threejs.component to be able to update it or access the data? Isn't that just a reverse version of what I have?

Comment: hmm. seems to be you need to use a service to do this and define a Subject type variable to pass your data

Comment: you could only use `@Output` to pass data from child component to parent component. I think here your approach is wrong

Comment: I tried injecting the service into the constructor, but its not accepting this.service.subscribe() in the ngOnInit(), the only thing I can access is the dataChange property.

Comment: sorry, I have made some mistake. I corrected it please check. should be like this `this.myService.$dataChange.subscribe`

Comment: From what I understand so far, Services are something along the lines of a singleton in c# (which I am familiar with) However I cant get it working still... I have exactly followed your code and everything makes sense to me. yet I am getting no event to be captured.

Comment: dose not fire the this.myService.$dataChange.subscribe method? when onChange() is called

Comment: I have checked that the onChange method is called, and it is. onChange is fired but the service subscription does not seem to respond.

Comment: does the  `$dataChange` like this  `$dataChange: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();` on the service ?

Comment: I've updated my question with the current situation. I am currently comparing yours and mine.

Comment: I checked your git code the issue with your imports please change the import of `ThreejsComponent` `import { SettingsService } from '../settings.service.js';` to `import { SettingsService } from '../settings.service';`  then it should work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've incorrectly declared your event:

```
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  settingsData: Settings;

  @Output() change: EventEmitter<Settings> = new EventEmitter<Settings>();


  onClick(){
    this.change.emit(this.settingsData);
  }
```

and then in your `app-threejs` component you should handle `(change)` event:

```
<app-threejs (change)="hello($event)"></app-threejs>


export class ThreejsComponent implements OnInit {
    hello(event:any) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Output emits an event from child to parent component, and in your code there is no parent-child relationship in your code (You can go with services in this case). But for handling the events using parent-child components you should do the below changes,

In `app.component.html` you have to includ only the threejs component.

```
<app-threejs (event)='UpdateWebGL($event)'><app-threejs>
```

Add toolbar in `threejs.component.html` like,

```
<app-toolbar><app-toolbar> <!-- when the emit function get called to looks for the parent component from here -->
```

Comment: Would I be better of using a service for this? Keeping in mind that this is a proof of concept and performance test? Or should I not really bother doing it in this case?